# using if in jquery and twig

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

I want to test if and id of an `<li>` is equal to a contact id or not, my jquery code is given as follow:

```
var points = new Array();
var i = 0;

$(this).toggleClass('selected');
$('#result').html($('#firstList .selected').clone());

$id = $(this).attr('id');
{% for contact in contacts %}
    $idd = "{{ contact.id }}";
    if ($id === $idd){
        points[i] = "{{ contact.gsmPrimary}}";
        i++;
        $('#result').val(points.join(';'));
    }
{% endfor %}
```

First, I get the `id` of each select element `li` and then I have a contact entity, I wanna to test if the id of the selected `<li>` equal to the contact.id or not, if equal I will add the `contact.gsmprimary` to a `textarea` named result

Thanks for help

Comment: How want you to debug it later? don't use twig to generate your javascript..

Comment: so never using javascript in twig template? I'am new in twig, I always use ajax with twig but just and asked if this method is good or not

Comment: Not, you can to use it, if you want, just don't mix it. You are generate a lot of traffic with this loop, and it's pain to debug resulted javascript... And it's always good - to put all your js to `*.js`

Comment: thank you very much, just I need a solution for this problem, because with ajax I can do it , but I need just using jquery to gain performance: if I have a list of contacts, it will be better to use comparison using javascript instead of quering database again.

Answer (score 3):

First of all separate JS script and twig template data.. Just take all contacts into one JS variable and use that variable to process in javascript

```
var contacts_json = $.parseJSON("{{ contacts|json_encode() }}"); 

var points = [];

$(this).toggleClass('selected');

$('#result').html($('#firstList .selected').clone());

$id = $(this).attr('id');

for(var i in contacts_json){

  if($id == contacts_json[i]['id']){

    points[] = contacts_json[i]['gsmPrimary'];
  }

}
$('#result').val(points.join(';'));
```

Comment: when runing my script, I get this result  var contacts_json = $.parseJSON("[{},{},{},{}]");

Comment: in twig i put dump(contacts) and i got this result:  array:4 [▼
'array:4 [▼
  0 => Contact {#850 ▼
    -id: 9
    -name: "sdfdf"
    -lastName: "taleb"
    -gsmPrimary: "+2222"
     }
  1 => Contact {#882 ▶}
  2 => Contact {#885 ▶}
  3 => Contact {#888 ▶}
] '

Comment: Can you implement [JsonSerializable](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/class.jsonserializable.php) interface for your `Contact` class?

Comment: @vp_arth , I tried to do that, can you give me please the best method to serialization with symfony 2.6  (I have a complexe entity, and I think it's a best idea to user serialization). thank you

Comment: See code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614374/added-columns-to-doctrine-entity-symfony-2-6-standard-are-not-recognized-by-do)

Comment: I get an error code , `L'utilisation de « getPreventDefault() » est obsolète. Utiliser « defaultPrevented » à la place. 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data`

Comment: [see the full problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136102/symfony-jquery-json-parse-expected-property-name)