# symfony , jquery, JSON.parse: expected property name

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, symfony

I have a problem with symfony, twig and jquery,

I want to get the list of contacts from database, and after that while clicking on the button, the list of contacts phone must be added to a field called `phone_list`.

In my controller I have:

```
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("select * from contact where id_user=$id");
$statement->execute();
$contacts = $statement->fetchAll();
$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($contacts, 'json');
```

In javascript area I have this code:

```
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       var contacts_json = $.parseJSON("{{ contacts|json_encode() }}");
       var points = [];
       var ii = 0;
       for (var i in contacts_json) {
           points[ii] = contacts_json[i]["id"];
           i++;
       }
       $('#destinationList').val(points.join(';'));
    }
    else {
        $('#destinationList').val("");
    }
});
```

In Twig I put `{{ dump(contacts) }}` and there is a result:

[image: dump output by Twig]

but when I try to execute the function, I get error in the console,

> L'utilisation de « getPreventDefault() » est obsolète. Utiliser « defaultPrevented » à la place. 
>   SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: I would recommend you to escape your parameter `$id` in the query. Also I would recommend you to read docs about PDO, because you have some extra not needed statements here... Why don't you use `$jsonContent` variable instead? It is already serialized. Why do you want to serialize the same data again in Twig?

Comment: I replaced  $contacts  by contentJson, but How I should do in the javascript code to work?

Comment: How is the javascript integrated in twig? It seems to me you are parsing a string. Have you tried using simple quotation marks `'{"p": 5}'` because of the json representation?